# NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories: Not creating directories or creating errors

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsfilemanager

In my app, when a user makes an in app purchase, the application needs to download and unzip a zip file to the app's documents folder. The zip file downloads and can be unzipped. I'm using [Objective Zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/) to unzip the archive. The problem is that when trying to create the folder paths for each file, the folders are never created, and there is no error.

Here is some sample code for the section where this is happening:

```
// Create file manager
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//Unzip
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
ZipFile *unzipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:[applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip",@"Mid America Oireachtas 2011"]] mode:ZipFileModeUnzip];
NSArray *infos= [unzipFile listFileInZipInfos];
for (FileInZipInfo *info in infos) {
    //NSLog(@"- %@ %@ %d (%d)", info.name, info.date, info.size, info.level);

    // Locate the file in the zip
    [unzipFile locateFileInZip:info.name];

    // Expand the file in memory
    ZipReadStream *read= [unzipFile readCurrentFileInZip];
    NSMutableData *data= [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:info.length];
    int bytesRead = [read readDataWithBuffer:data];
    [read finishedReading];
    NSString *appSupportFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *pathfull = [appSupportFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:info.name];
    NSString *path = [[pathfull stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] copy];
    NSError *errorw;
    NSRange range = [path rangeOfString:@"__MACOSX"];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"last: %@", [path lastPathComponent]);
        if ([fileMgr createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&errorw]) {
            NSLog(@"Create Folder: %@", path);
            NSLog(@"Directory Win: %@", errorw);
            if (![[pathfull pathExtension] isEqualToString:@""] && ![[[pathfull lastPathComponent] substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"." ]) {
                [data writeToFile:pathfull atomically:NO];
            }
        }
        else {
            //NSLog(@"Create Folder: %@", path);
            NSLog(@"Directroy Fail: %@", errorw);
        }
    }
}

[unzipFile close];

//delete zip
// For error information
NSError *error;

if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip",@"Mid America Oireachtas 2011"]] error:&error] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"File Deleted");
}

//delete zip
// For error information
NSError *error;

if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip",@"My Zip"]] error:&error] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"File Deleted");
}
```

Here is relevant snippet of output from the log file:

```
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.509 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Create Folder: /Users/Brandon/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/436C2C49-D79B-4CDA-B0AA-15BB98F6F75E/WhatsMyStageOn.app/
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.510 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Directory Win: (null)
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.510 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Create Folder: /Users/Brandon/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/436C2C49-D79B-4CDA-B0AA-15BB98F6F75E/WhatsMyStageOn.app/Documents/Mid America Oireachtas 2011
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.510 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Directory Win: (null)
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.510 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Create Folder: /Users/Brandon/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/436C2C49-D79B-4CDA-B0AA-15BB98F6F75E/WhatsMyStageOn.app/Documents
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.510 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Directory Win: (null)
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.511 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Create Folder: /Users/Brandon/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/436C2C49-D79B-4CDA-B0AA-15BB98F6F75E/WhatsMyStageOn.app/Documents/__MACOSX
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.511 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Directory Win: (null)
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.511 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Create Folder: /Users/Brandon/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/436C2C49-D79B-4CDA-B0AA-15BB98F6F75E/WhatsMyStageOn.app/Documents/__MACOSX/Mid America Oireachtas 2011
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.511 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Directory Win: (null)
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.511 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Create Folder: /Users/Brandon/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/436C2C49-D79B-4CDA-B0AA-15BB98F6F75E/WhatsMyStageOn.app/Documents/Mid America Oireachtas 2011
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.512 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Directory Win: (null)
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.544 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Create Folder: /Users/Brandon/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/436C2C49-D79B-4CDA-B0AA-15BB98F6F75E/WhatsMyStageOn.app/Documents/Mid America Oireachtas 2011/Attractions
    2012-01-04 17:12:51.544 WhatsMyStageOn[3232:15503] Directory Win: (null)
```

Reading the NSFileManager documentation, this is what should output in the log, but, No folders are created.

EDIT: Fixed not using documents issue, still have same problem as decried before edit.

EDIT: Updated code to working solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be writing to the app's bundle itself. Try this:

```
NSString *appSupportFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [appSupportFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:info.name];
```

Comment: I fixed the "Documents" Folder Problem. but the app is still not creating any directories, or giving me any errors.

Comment: You didn't actually fix the problem though. Now you're simply writing to a subfolder of the app bundle called documents. You shouldn't be writing to a path that begins with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` at all.

Comment: Perfect. This worked! Thanks!  One question though, the first method I used with NSBundle, and your code return the same path. Why does this work and the first one doesn't.

Comment: It's not returning the same path. If you look carefully, you'll note that previously the path included the app bundle (WhatsMyStageOn.app) itself. It shouldn't any longer. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're able to create directories directly inside of WhatsMyStageOn.app/, try creating them inside of your Documents directory.

```
NSMutableString *path = [info.name mutableCopy];
path = [[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] mutableCopy];
path = [NSMutableString  stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", applicationDocumentsDir, path];
```

You have a line at the bottom that deletes the correct file path inside of Documents, but your original path variable points at the bundle directory, not the Documents directory.

Comment: Whoops, How did I not see that. I fixed the documents problem. The folder "Documents" is now added to each log. But it still is not working, or throwing any errors.